# Get rid of [scaling]

Tags: discussion, tags

[scaling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scaling) is a tag that covers multiple disparate areas. Some would be better retagged as [display-scaling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/display-scaling), while others deal with image and video scaling (and even things like PDF zoom!) and perhaps don't need a scaling-related tag at all.

Comment: I've always used it to indicate a question about the residue that sometimes occurs when I accidentally boil a pot of water dry. In fact, that's how I got here! :-)

Comment: @MrWonderful what hardware are you using? My MBP doesn't even come with a coffee cup holder!